# Pipeline passed but csv file not created

Tags: pandas, csv, gitlab, pipeline, cicd

I am running a python script in a pipeline on gitlab, which at the end creates two csv files. The pipeline is successful, however the csv files are not created. I tested the process on my local and the files get created.

This is one example of python script which doesn't create the csv file even though the pipeline is successful.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
  "calories": [420, 380, 390],
  "duration": [50, 40, 45]
}

#load data into a DataFrame object:
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)
df.to_csv('test.csv')
```

Here is the configuration of the .gitlab-ci.yml file:

```
to_create:
  script:
    - python to_create.py
```

How can I create the test.csv file through the pipeline run on gitlab?

Comment: how do you determine whether files are created in pipeline?

Comment: I updated the question with the configuration of the .gitlab-ci.yml file. I am looking into the repository, to check for `test.csv` file and it isn't there. This is the only way of determining if the file exists.

Comment: do you mean you want to checkin file to git repository in gitlab ci? you should run git command such as clone, add, commit, push, etc. but it is often bad practice to change the repo itself in ci.

Comment: yes, I want to change the csv file from the pipeline. That file should be updated daily with new data, so the only way I found is to schedule the pipeline to run at a certain hour, everyday. Is there any other option for this which is not bad practice? -as you say this is

Comment: i'd like to store the data elsewhere, outside the repo. maybe in another repo, or database, or http storage, whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To store the `test.csv` as a Job Artifact, you can add the following lines to the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file.

```
to_create:
  script:
    - python to_create.py
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - test.csv
```

For every run of this job, a `test.csv` file will be stored within GitLab.

Read more about Job Arifacts, here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/job_artifacts.html

Comment: Thanks, but how could I then use the test.csv file within the project? How could I read it inside the project?

Comment: From your machine, or from subsequent steps in the pipeline?

Comment: Well, I am using gitlab to run the pipeline as it supports files over 100MB, but I am hosting the project which uses the csv files on github. So I would need to access those csv files in the github project...

Comment: You can manually download the artifacts to your computer, and add them to the repository. Or, you can programmatically retrieve them via GitLab's API. https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/job_artifacts.html

Comment: Thanks so much for the documentation!! I tried updating my pipeline with the example you provided for `artifact_download` and I managed to have a successful pipeline and to download the artifacts archive. However, can you help me on where is the zip file of the artifacts downloaded? I am new to CI/CD and I am unfamiliar with how it works